# Scheduled scaling of Azure VMSS (via Runbook)

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, azure-vm-scale-set, runbook

Is it possible to set up specified schedule based on time conditions to increase and/or decrease Azure VMSS ignoring any other triggers? Is it possible to set it up via Runbook modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule based autoscale for Azure VM scale sets is supported. See this article on advanced autoscale for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-advanced-autoscale-virtual-machine-scale-sets